# SQL Server: using stored procedures to dynamically alter a sequence of orders based on certain conditions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, powerapps, power-automate

I have a table that is being generated via `INSERT INTO` from a view. The data looks like this:

```
Priority    ID  Status
1   108999_1_S010   Planned
1   108999_1_S020   Planned
1   108996_1_S030   Planned
1   108996_1_S035   Planned
1   108996_1_S040   Planned
1   108996_1_S050   Planned
1   108996_1_S060   Planned
1   108996_1_S070   Planned
1   108996_1_S080   Planned
1   108996_1_S090   Planned
1   108996_1_S100   Planned
1   108996_1_S110   Planned
1   108996_1_S120   Planned
2   108999_2_S010   Planned
2   108999_2_S020   Planned
2   108996_2_S030   Planned
2   108996_2_S035   Planned
2   108996_2_S040   Planned
2   108996_2_S050   Planned
2   108996_2_S060   Planned
2   108996_2_S070   Planned
2   108996_2_S080   Planned
2   108996_2_S090   Planned
2   108996_2_S100   Planned
2   108996_2_S110   Planned
2   108996_2_S120   Planned
3   108999_3_S010   Planned
3   108999_3_S020   Planned
3   108996_3_S030   Planned
3   108996_3_S035   Planned
3   108996_3_S040   Planned
3   108996_3_S050   Planned
3   108996_3_S060   Planned
3   108996_3_S070   Planned
3   108996_3_S080   Planned
3   108996_3_S090   Planned
3   108996_3_S100   Planned
3   108996_3_S110   Planned
3   108996_3_S120   Planned
4   108999_4_S010   Planned
4   108999_4_S020   Planned
4   108996_4_S030   Planned
4   108996_4_S035   Planned
4   108996_4_S040   Planned
4   108996_4_S050   Planned
4   108996_4_S060   Planned
4   108996_4_S070   Planned
4   108996_4_S080   Planned
4   108996_4_S090   Planned
4   108996_4_S100   Planned
4   108996_4_S110   Planned
4   108996_4_S120   Planned
5   110225_1_S010   Planned
5   110225_1_S020   Planned
5   110224_1_S030   Planned
5   110224_1_S035   Planned
5   110224_1_S040   Planned
5   110224_1_S050   Planned
5   110224_1_S060   Planned
5   110224_1_S070   Planned
5   110224_1_S080   Planned
5   110224_1_S090   Planned
5   110224_1_S100   Planned
5   110224_1_S110   Planned
5   110224_1_S120   Planned
```

The `Priority` is being generated upon insertion using the `ROW_NUMBER()` function on the view. As you can see from the `ID` column, there are 14 sub-stations for any given order so there will be fourteen equivalent numbers for each priority. This is all well and good, but this table is being continuously updated via PowerApps and Power Automate. There are two requirements that I have for this table:

- If a new set of orders come in from the underlying source view and their `priority` is, for example 3, then I would need the current orders with `priority` (3, 4, 5) to all shift one to (4, 5, 6).
- If the `status` column of a particular `ID` changes from "Planned" to "Completed", then that row's `Priority` becomes 0 and the next `Priority` order for that station shifts to that position. (For example, if the order with `ID` "108996_2_S030" (which has `priority` 2) is finished, then the `priority` of this order becomes 0 and order "108996_3_S030" becomes 2. And the subsequent orders all become `Priority - 1`.

I'm thinking I need two separate stored procedures for this. Triggered by insertion from the view and upon change of the the `status` column. However, I am not sure how to write them so they don't interfere with each other.

Originally, I was going to just recalculate the `priority` entirely every time one of these triggers, but the caveat is that we also need to be able to manually change the `priority` via PowerAppss so I don't want to reset those changes.

Does anybody have any clue on how I could write stored procedures that will achieve the result for me?

Comment: If a new set of orders comes in with priority 3 and at almost exactly the same time, another set of orders comes in with priority 4, what happens if the second update statement (the one to update the (4,5,6) records) runs before the first? You could get different results in that scenario depending on which update ran first, and that may not be what you want.

Comment: A good point, @dcp. Those update statements would be lumped together and it would have to go based on the highest `priority`.  So with priorities 3 and 4, then (3,4,5) would become (5,6,7).

Comment: Handling a new set of orders sounds like something an `instead of insert` trigger could manage gracefully. If there is a collision on `Priority` between the new and existing data then it would adjust the `Priority` of the existing rows and then perform the `insert`. Absent a collision it can simply `insert` the new data. I'm failing to grasp what your second case, `Status` "Completed", is really trying to do.

Comment: @HABO, Unfortunately, SQL Triggers do not play well with PowerApps :(. I'll have to use stored procedures for now. I am thinking of storing the "insert" results in a temp table within the stored procedure and then using that to construct variables to determine the last `priority` of the insert table. Then I can use that to update the `priority` of any order that is sequentially beyond that variable. Thoughts?

Comment: @HABO, the first bullet point on my question refers to the "flow" of orders. Operators should work on the first order, then the second one, etc. However, each order is being individually worked on at different subassembly stations. "S030" as a station will work on it first, then "S035", then "S040", etc. So for each individual workstation, I would also like to adjust the flow based on what orders are being done.

Answer (score 0):

So here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Workstation] ORDER BY [Ship Date], [RootID], [Workstation]) as Priority
      ,bm.[Customer]
      ,[ProductionOrder]
      ,[RootID]
      ,[SalesOrder]
      ,[Line]
      ,[QtyID]
      ,[TotalQty]
      ,[Material]
      ,[Config]
      ,[Description]
      ,[Workstation]
      ,[ConfigGroup]
      ,[Business Unit]
      ,[StartDate]
      ,[FinishDate]
      ,[ShipDate]
INTO #OrderInsert
FROM 
[BoomsBuildMaster] as bm
INNER JOIN
[BoomsBuildScheduleTEST] as bs
ON bm.RootID = bs.[Sales Order] + '_' + bs.[Line No]
WHERE bm.ProductionOrder NOT IN (SELECT [ProductionOrder] FROM [BoomsBuilder])
AND bs.Status = 'Ready'

UPDATE [BoomsBuilder]
SET Priority = Priority + (SELECT (MAX(Priority) - MIN(Priority) + 1) FROM #OrderInsert)
WHERE Priority >= (SELECT MIN(Priority) FROM #OrderInsert)

INSERT INTO [BoomsBuilder]
(
       [Priority]
      ,[Customer]
      ,[ProductionOrder]
      ,[RootID]
      ,[SalesOrder]
      ,[Line]
      ,[QtyID]
      ,[TotalQty]
      ,[Material]
      ,[Config]
      ,[Description]
      ,[Workstation]
      ,[ConfigGroup]
      ,[Business Unit]
      ,[StartDate]
      ,[FinishDate]
      ,[ShipDate]
)
SELECT * FROM #OrderInsert;
```

What's happening here: this stored procedure will fire when table `[BoomsBuildScheduleTEST]` gets a row updated to `Status` "ready".

So let's say three new orders are entered in at the same time with priorities (5, 6, 7). Then the current (5, 6, 7) orders would be pushed to (8, 9, 10) and anything after that will be pushed out to (11, 12, 13...). And then the new (5, 6, 7) would be inserted.

This will work for a single order being inserted, or even multiple orders that are sequential in priority. HOWEVER, it will not work if, for example, two new orders are added in and the priorities are (3,7) respectively. Not sure what to do in that case.